# How do I read numeric values as factors in R from dta file (unused argument error)?

Tags: r

I'm new to R, I have a DTA File with a bunch of numeric values, but i want to read them as factors, I tried this method

```
Dwelling <- read_dta("C:/Dwelling.dta",colClasses="factor")
```

but it keeps giving me the following error

```
Error in read_dta("C:/Dwelling.dta",  : 
 unused argument (colClasses = "factor")
```

any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming `read_dta` comes from the **haven** package? (That's information that you should always put in questions!) If so, there isn't such an argument. Presumably you'd have to convert the columns yourself in R once the data is read in.

Comment: it is from that package, how would i do that though?

Comment: If you're familiar with **dplyr**, I would probably do something like `... %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,as.factor)`.